# The driver has not received any packets from the server. Docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker

I have a dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM openjdk:18  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY ./target/weatertop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/weatertop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  
CMD ["java", "-jar", "weatertop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'  
services:  
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_DATABASE: weather
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
    ports:
      - 8090:8090

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  activemq:
    image: rmohr/activemq
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8161:8161
      - 61616:61616

  myproject:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - activemq
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=12345
      - ACTIVEMQ_URL=tcp://activemq:61616
```

The error occurs only when connecting to the database.
The connector is connected in pom.xml.
I tried connecting to the database via connector, everything works fine, but there are some problems in docker.

Error code:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Answer (score 1):

The application has the URL defined as:

```
- DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather
```

But since you are running it inside a docker container, "localhost" is something else.

Try changing the url to this:

```
  - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/weather
```

(Within docker-compose, network to specific services works, by just using the container name)

Comment: This is always the right answer. I wonder if you can still get 25 points for answering it, or whether the question will be closed as a duplicate!